# Insert into db not working in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite, insert

HI Iam using SQLite db in iOS.I have created DB successfully and table also. But when i tried to save textfield contents into database but it showing "failed to add contact "alert.

I have doubt in my INSERT string and the way i assign textfield values in it.

can anyone please help me to solve this?

```
    - (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &myDatabase) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"INSERT INTO LubnaNewUser (name,address,phonenumber,tier) VALUES (\"%@%@%@%@\")",
                               name.text,address.text,phonenumber.text,tier.text];

        const char*insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, insert_stmt,  -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            statusOfAddingToDB = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Text added -- %@", name.text];
        } else {
            statusOfAddingToDB = @"Failed to add contact";
        }

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"DB Status" message: statusOfAddingToDB delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(myDatabase);
    }
}
```

[image]
new code
[image]

```
 if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &myDatabase) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        //Select all from SAMPLETABLE. This includes the 'id' column and 'message' column.
        NSString *querySQL = @"SELECT * FROM LubnaNewUser";
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *text = [[NSString alloc]
                                  initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)]; //Num 1 means on what column. Column 0 = 'id' column while Column 1 = 'message' column in our query result.
                [list addObject:text];
                //NSLog(@"count: %d", [list count]);
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(myDatabase);
    }
```

Comment: try  VALUES (\"%@,%@,%@,%@\") instead of  VALUES (\"%@%@%@%@\")

Comment: @stosha That is still a single string.

Comment: can u check my screenshots attached to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [sqlite3_errmsg](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) to get an error message.

Anyway, you have to write four values into the VALUES clause:

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"INSERT INTO LubnaNewUser (name,address,phonenumber,tier) VALUES ('%@','%@','%@','%@')",
     name.text,address.text,phonenumber.text,tier.text];
```

However, this will blow up when any of these strings contains a quote.
Better use parameters:

```
const char *insertSQL = "INSERT INTO LubnaNewUser (name,address,phonenumber,tier) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, insertSQL, -1, &statement, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [name.text        UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [address.text     UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [phonenumber.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [tier.text        UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
...
```

Comment: working like charm....but i have another problem in select query .I need every column .But here am getting only second column.

Comment: can u please check my updated question with select query

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.